# I got stuck on this "Cookie "mojolicious" is bigger than 4KiB"

Tags: perl, cookies, mojolicious

It seems I can't get rid of this "Cookie "myname" is bigger than 4KiB" error

in my startup sub:

```
my $app      = $self->sessions(Mojolicious::Sessions->new);
my $sessions = $app->sessions;

$sessions->cookie_name('cookie_name');
# $sessions->max_cookie_size(4096*2); <= that's what I'm looking for
```

Any ideas on how to get around this?
Is there a way to increase and check the cookie size?
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a limit for cookie size on the browser side.

Comment: Generally speaking, you should store not much more than an identifier in a user's session, then use that identifier to load their real session data from a file or database.

Answer (score 2):

[RFC 6265](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6265.txt), suggests (SHOULD) that browsers allow at least 4096 for the entire collection of cookie data (not just the value):

> At least 4096 bytes per cookie (as measured by the sum of the
> length of the cookie's name, value, and attributes).

That's the number that the popular browsers support. If they get a bigger cookie, they likely ignore it.

Note that if you have a large cookie, the client has to send that back. That might have to split a request, even if it doesn't need the cookie, to be split over several packets and so on. Small wins matter, so the RFC goes on to say:

> Servers SHOULD use as few and as small cookies as possible to avoid
> reaching these implementation limits and to minimize network
> bandwidth due to the Cookie header being included in every request.

Beyond that, realize that storing a bunch of information in the cookie means that the client side has the opportunity to change that information in some way that allows them to do things you don't intend.

On the technical side, there are various things that you can do to shorten a string by using your 4096 octets more efficiently. Things the uuencode (7-bit encoding), Perl's `pack` for numbers, and other binary techniques (Sereal, msgpack, whatever) can squeeze more info in.